# Encrypting a message in message

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I just started learning `bash`, and I have a question.

I have to do a codebook encryption. For instance, switching the letter of the alphabet with the given pattern of letters. For example:

```
Hello World. has to become Qlxxa vaoxk.
```

But I'm getting a different result using this command:

```
 echo $line | tr 'a-z' "$line1"
```

line has my message
line1 has the pattern
The result shifts by one more letter than what I wanted.

Comment: This is the pattern :
cijklmpqrstxyzabnodefufuvwgh
CDEMNOPQRSTGHUVXYZAIJKLWBF
So a should be replaced by c and A by C

Comment: $line1 is the pattern

Comment: I see you have a space in your pattern, is that the case in the actual variable too? That might be the culprit.

Comment: sry when the lower case letters in the pattern are on the first line and the upper ones on the second line in a file

Comment: Also, if you have lowercase and uppercase in your "pattern set", you need them in the source set too, i.e. `'a-zA-Z'`.

Comment: yeah I just changed it

Comment: So the upper case letters are now replaced correctly but the lower case ones are shifted by one letter

Comment: Try to examine the exact pattern that is passed in to `tr` (e.g. by letting the shell print it out with `echo "$line1"` just before). That might help in debugging.

Comment: So my current output is now Plxxa vaoxk

Comment: echo $line1 gives the space between the 2 lines in the pattern as you said

Comment: Do you know how to avoid the space ?

Comment: Either don't have whitespace there in the first place (i.e. put everything on a single line), or remove it with `line1="${line1// /}"`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accept below to make this official. :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was in how the pattern was supplied; it was read from a file with the lowercase substitutions on one line, and the uppercase ones on the second line. Reading it with

```
line1="$(<pattern.txt)"
```

results in whitespace between the lowercase and uppercase patterns, thus making all characters appear shifted.

The solution is to remove the whitespace after reading with

```
line1="${line1// /}"
```